ArrayList.removeFirst() throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but was synchronized
Having this Threadpool:
package xxx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * A thread pool that hold an amount of work. During execution the amount of
 * work may grow.
 * 
 * @param <A> The work
 */
public class DepleatingFiFoThreadPool<A> {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DepleatingFiFoThreadPool.class.getCanonicalName());

    public record Socket<A>(A r, String threadPostfix) {
    }

    private final Thread[] threadsRunning;
    private final ArrayList<Socket<A>> unstartedRunnables = new ArrayList<>();
    private int nextFreeSocketIndex = 0;
    private final Consumer<Throwable> errorHandler;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean waitingForLock = false;

    private final String prefix;
    private final Consumer<A> invoker;

    /**
     * Create the threadpool.
     * 
     * @param threadsRunningMax The maximum of Threads running at the same time,
     *                          must be higher than <code>0</code>
     * @param errorHandler      The handler in case of problems, never
     *                          <code>null</code>
     * @param prefix            The prefix for the pool, required for debugging
     *                          purposes, never <code>null</code>
     * @param invoker           The invoker who encapsule the work, never
     *                          <code>null</code>
     */
    public DepleatingFiFoThreadPool(final int threadsRunningMax, final Consumer<Throwable> errorHandler,
            final String prefix, final Consumer<A> invoker) {
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.invoker = invoker;
        this.threadsRunning = new Thread[threadsRunningMax];
    }

    /**
     * Add and start a thread.
     * 
     * Work after returning from {@link #executeUntilDeplated(long)} will not be
     * executed.
     * 
     * @param notRunningThread The not running work that is designated to be done
     * @param threadPostfix    The postfix of the thread, never <code>null</code>
     */
    public void addAndStartThread(final A notRunningThread, final String threadPostfix) {
        var mustCallLater = false;
        if (nextFreeSocketIndex < threadsRunning.length) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (nextFreeSocketIndex < threadsRunning.length) {
                    start(notRunningThread, threadPostfix);
                } else {
                    mustCallLater = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            mustCallLater = true;
        }
        if (mustCallLater) {
            unstartedRunnables.add(new Socket<A>(notRunningThread, threadPostfix));
        }
    }

    private void finished() {
        synchronized (this) {
            threadsRunning[--nextFreeSocketIndex] = null;
            if (nextFreeSocketIndex == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (waitingForLock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Socket<A> e = null;
                if (!unstartedRunnables.isEmpty()) {
                    synchronized (unstartedRunnables) {
                        if (!unstartedRunnables.isEmpty()) {
                            e = unstartedRunnables.removeFirst();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (e != null) {
                    start(e.r, e.threadPostfix);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void start(final A notRunningThread, final String name) {
        var socket = nextFreeSocketIndex++;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    invoker.accept(notRunningThread);
                } catch (Throwable e) { // fault barrier!
                    try {
                        errorHandler.accept(e);
                    } catch (Throwable ta) {
                        ta.addSuppressed(e);
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ta.getMessage(), ta);
                    }
                }
                finished();
            }
        }, prefix + name);
        threadsRunning[socket] = t;
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the threads and every subsequent thread that is added during the
     * progress.
     * 
     * @param timeoutMs The timeout in miliseconds, should be an positive value
     * @return <code>false</code> if the timeout has reached, <code>true</code>
     *         otherwise
     * @throws InterruptedException If the thread has been interrupted (maybe
     *                              shutdown of application)
     */
    public boolean executeUntilDeplated(final long timeoutMs) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicBoolean resultHolder = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        if (nextFreeSocketIndex > 0) {
            Thread timeout = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeoutMs);
                    resultHolder.set(false);
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.log(Level.FINE, "Not a bug, timeout not reached, watchdog not required.", e);
                }
            });
            timeout.start();
            if (nextFreeSocketIndex > 0) {
                waitingForLock = true;
                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait(timeoutMs);
                    } finally {
                        timeout.interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultHolder.get();
    }
}

A exception is thrown sometimes having this Stacktrace:
Exception in thread "NN/SQL-caller" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: last source index 50 out of bounds for object array[49]
  at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.fastRemove(ArrayList.java:724)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeFirst(ArrayList.java:573)
  at xxx.DepleatingFiFoThreadPool.finished(DepleatingFiFoThreadPool.java:74)
  at xxx.DepleatingFiFoThreadPool$1.run(DepleatingFiFoThreadPool.java:100)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)

I am not able to debug this because it appears only once every three to five weeks.
I use this test but I could not find the problem:
public void testMassiveQueuedFunction() throws InterruptedException {
    var dtp = new DepleatingFiFoThreadPool<Runnable>(100, x -> System.out.println(x), "testQueueFunction",
            Runnable::run);
    var l = new CountDownLatch(0);
    Runnable wait = () -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
            l.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
        dtp.addAndStartThread(wait, i + "");
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    dtp.executeUntilDeplated(3000);
    long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    assert l.getCount() == 0 : "Await a count of 0 but has: " + l.getCount();
    assert took < 2900 : "Should execute faster but took: " + took;
}

Can someone suggest a better unit-test?

Looks to me like nextFreeSocketIndex has value 50 but the array threadsRunning only has 49 elements. Either you are assigning an incorrect value to nextFreeSocketIndex, or the value is not synchronized between threads. Maybe you need to add volatile to the declaration of nextFreeSocketIndex?

I think the problem is that the add to unstartedRunnables (and ArrayList itself) isn't synchronized.
I guess the exceptions happens when unstartedRunnables changes it's size while in ArrayList.fastRemove

Actually its very easy to reproduce, you need to use more threads than 1, here https://pastebin.com/GrdFGY6x I reproduce it immediately - also in debugger.

@marcinj Can you answer as an unit-test?

Just a note, threadsRunningMax and initialising all appear to exist at the one instant , so threadsRunningMax cannot be changed after it starts because you are using final variables. If it starts with less than enough then there cannot be an element for that job.

I just noticed too, you must "initialise all final variables in the constructor , particularly the Thread array threads themselves"!    Because of this problem your code is actually erroneous, and the compiler and JVM are only being kind to you !!!

If you could have a problem with the actual numbers at initialisation, consider using a linkedhaskmap or arraylist class. Too consider using "package private" class level to prevent unauthorised runtime module access.

@SamuelMarchant Using the Socket as key? Hm, this means I can not call the same socket twice. I need to be able to use the same socket multiple times.

What is the fully qualified Socket package and class(presumably Socket class or interface)?

Yes, I synchronized removeFirst but I missed to synchronized unstartedRunnables.add.
TLDR;
If I run the removeFirst, there is a small chance that add adds a new element asynchroniously. We have two arrays having differrent sizes. That is why the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown. In order to solve the problem, I need to synchronize the unstartedRunnables.add call.
A good improvement suggestion however came from @rzwitserloot in order to not synchonize against the this-object.

You do not appear to understand how java's threading model works at all. It's hard to highlight any particular line. I'll try:
This:
if (mustCallLater) {
  unstartedRunnables.add(new Socket<A>(notRunningThread, threadPostfix));
}

is fundamentally broken. You are attemping to use advanced footgun concepts such as double checked locking, and yet you also say things like:

@marcinj Can you answer as an unit-test?

Which indicates you should put the foot guns away.
JMM isn't deterministic
The fundamental problem with your understanding is in how you appear to think that the behaviour of java's threading, i.e. when a write in one thread can be seen in another thread, is deterministic. It is not - hence, it is not possible to 'show' that your code is broken with a simple unit test.
The thing you need to wrap your head around is this:
If you attempt to observe in line B a change that  line A made and there is no HappensBefore(A, B) then your code is broken.
And that's because the JMM (Java Memory Model; that section of the JVM spec that describes how observability works) says that the JVM is fee to do whatever it wants - line B may observe what A did or it may not observe what A did. If you run it 5000 times, it may show you what A did all 5000 times, and then tomorrow when you have the important demo, it no longer does that.
Your code must function properly regardless of the 'choice' the JVM makes; you cannot ask the JVM what choice it has made/will make and you can't force it to make a choice other than by establishing HappensBefore which is the one and only way the JMM dictates you can guarantee observability. You can't write unit tests because without HB(A, B) it is still possible that B always observes the changes A makes. Today. On your machine. With this song on your music player. With this full moon. Who knows what happens tomorrow? When the song ends? When you run this on a different VM? Or a different version.
A few important facts about HB:

HB merely guarantees data observability. HB(A, B) does mean A actually runs before B. Merely that B cannot observe any state as it was before A changed it. For example, if B doesn't try to observe anything A did, then the JVM is free to run A after B. Also, if B can observe A has not run yet by way of some timing issue, that doesn't count.

There is no such thing as 'eventually'. If there is no HB(A, B) then any change A made need not be observable in B. Not even if 5 days have passed and the CPU has been sitting there idling all 5 days, and 20 garbage collection cycles have occurred in between.


So, how do you establish that all important HB? There's a list of explicit actions that establish it in the JMM. That is the only way. Here's the important parts of that list:

The 'natural way': HB(A, B) is established for all lines running in the same thread if B is ordered after A. In other words, given, all in one thread: int x = 5; x = 10; System.out.println(x);, that cannot possibly print 5.

Thread management: thread.start() is HB relative to the first line in the run() method of that thread, and the last line in a thread before it ends is HB relative to thread.join() returning.

synchronized (x) - synchronized blocks run in some order, and the last line in a sync block is HB relative to the first line in another sync block if the other sync block is ordered later. Of course, this only counts if the references are the same - if one block does synchronized(foo) and another synchronized(bar) no HB is established at all.

reads and writes to volatile fields also do this, but it can be difficult to know which one is first and which one is second.


Your mistakes
You make a change to unstartedRunnables without anything that can possibly establish HB. That means the change you make here may not be observable from anywhere. It doesn't matter that you can synchronized (this) elsewhere; both the writes and the reads need to use synchronized in other to get the HB established by synchronized.
Dangerous locking
this tends to be 'public', and locks should never be public unless extensively documented and considered part of your API. If that's too long to remember, 'locks should never be public' is an acceptable shorthand for that if you want to simplify things. You have a private field named lock right there - all those sync blocks should be synchronized (lock) instead!
For the same reason public fields are a bad idea, public locks are a bad idea.
Badly reinventing wheels
If you are getting the sense 'wait.. that means.. any concurrency code is utterly untestable and that means it is impossible to it right!' you have the right idea. Hence, writing your own low-level concurrency tools is rocket science and you should be incredibly smart, and slave away spending hours per line, to do this. Mere mortals should generally not attempt it.
Instead, look at the java.util.concurrent package. What you're trying to do? It has classes that do exactly that, and they were written in that extremely plodding, careful manner, and have been used and tested by millions of people.
executeUntilDeplated
I don't know what that code is meant to do, but it doesn't appear to do anything useful. In the javadoc it says:

If the thread has been interrupted (maybe shutdown of application)

This is wrong. interruptions do not occur due to shutdown of an app. Threads just end, they don't throw InterruptedExceptions. Only one thing causes InterruptedException: t.interrupt(). And nothing in the core java packages call that (except a select few execution pool things in j.u.c and they document it extensively). It means what you want it to mean, in other words.

I presume you are referring to this footgun. Is that correct?

@Abra Yes. Double checked locking is extremely easy to mess up and if you do mess it up it is hard to know that you did. For example, the DCL used in the code provided in the question is probably not going to do what the author thinks it does.

inconcrete, demonizing, absolutistic. Not helpful, not a bit.
